# Starting new activity from a non activity class in a constructor

Tags: android

I know it's been alot of questions like this, but I didn't find the answer.

```
public class Model3D extends ARObject implements Serializable{

    public Model3D(Context context)
    {
        super("model", "", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Model3D(Model model,String patternName)
    {
        super("model", patternName, 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, toast.class);
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}

public class toast extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Let's do some search action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

everytime i do this my program stops working.
Actually i want to call intent in the constructor because i want to show a toast message and if i use toast message in constructor it gives error.

plz help
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why an extra Activity if you just want to show a toast?
You can show toasts only on the ui thread. So if your constructor is not called in the UI Thread you must have a reference to an Activity or Handler.

```
public Model3D(Model model, String patternName, final Activity activity) {
    super("model", patternName, 80.0, new double[] { 0, 0 });

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Let's do some search action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          }
    });
}
```

Comment: actually i am new to it and dont know much about threads but i have only 1 thread its not allowing me to use toast in this class it gives error :(

Comment: Post you stacktrace and we might be able to help you.

Comment: i am working on augmentedreality and is using andarmodelviwer..in its model3D class i want to show toast message